# Install Spark and Hadoop in the same machine

Tags: apache-spark, apache-hadoop, pyspark

I'm trying to install Spark Apache and Hadoop in the same machine. Spark will be used to process data, and HDFS from Hadoop will be used to store data. I first started by installing spark and it worked perfectly. But, when I started installing Hadoop and set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable HDFS worked, but spark break down and shows: `Files was unexpected at this time`. when I launched it. When I deleted `JAVA_HOME`, Spark worked again but it's not the case for HDFS. What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hadoop stack is difficult to setup and people complain that you can't trust any answers to problems over 6-12 months old. I would recommend getting a pre-configured Hadoop/Spark setup from Cloudera or HortonWorks. Both have free community editions.